# Why does using a normal map consisting only of pure blue make my model translucent?

Tags: normal-map

I read online that using a normal map consisting only of a single color in RGB (128,128,255) makes normals completely perpendicular to all polygons on the mesh

I was puzzled by this and decided to see if a almost nearly blue color (0,0,255) would have the same effect. Here is the map itself:

[image]

Here is what the mesh looks like without the map:
[image]

And finally here is what it looks like with the blue image texture applied using the normal map node:

[image]

Note the translucency. The next picture showcases this effect even more:
[image]

Why exactly does a completely blue normal map cause such an effect? What is the reason behind the translucency here?